# Как правильно реализовать обработку данных и отправку формы

Tags: php

Есть страница с простой формой, на форме кнопка и поле для ввода чисел. Мне нужно проверить то, что ввел пользователь, если он ввел не число или число меньше 200, то сообщить ему об этом. Если он ввел все верно, то перенаправить его на другую страницу передав туда введенное им число методом post. Как это правильно сделать?

Я пока дошел вот до чего, форма у меня передается ajax-ом на сервер, там я проверяю данные и возвращаю json, разобрав который могу сообщить пользователю, что он ввел некорректные данные, но как теперь передать все это post методом на другую страницу?

Comment: Приведите код ваших стараний, очень сложно гадать по тексту

Comment: @Taarim, решил вопрос динамическим созданием формы и отправкой её на сервер посредством jquery